# Integrating Smart Battery and Charger into ESP32 System: PlatformIO, Arduino, and Stepper Motors

Tags: arduino-esp32

Hello StackOverflow community,

I'm relatively new to the field and currently working on a project that involves integrating a smart battery and charger into an ESP32 system. The system also includes two stepper motors controlled by the Arduino framework and PlatformIO in VSCode. My colleague is handling the motor and microcontroller aspects.

Here are the key components and details of the project:

Microcontroller: ESP32
Stepper Motors: Handled by 'arduino-libraries/Stepper' and 'waspinator/AccelStepper'
Bluetooth Communication: 'mbed-seeed/BluetoothSerial'
Battery and Charger: Smart battery and charger (details to be provided)
I'm facing challenges in understanding how to seamlessly integrate the smart battery and charger into the existing system. The battery charger is not always connected but is plugged in by the user when charging is required.

Specific Questions:

How can I efficiently manage power resources and communication between the ESP32 and the smart battery?
Are there specific libraries or configurations within PlatformIO that I should consider for handling intermittent connections with the charger?
Any best practices or examples for integrating a smart battery system into an ESP32 project with PlatformIO?
I appreciate any guidance, code snippets, or references that can point me in the right direction. Thank you for your assistance!

I just started working on the project so I did not try anything yet, I am still looking for appropriate libraries to take as reference or use. I will be using .cpp and .h files instead of .ino, I am not sure if this is the best practice to this project.

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, for ESP chips/boards, they are power hungry and for any system running of battery juice you would want to consider using different ESP sleep modes or switching on/off bluetooth modem when not needed.

Depending on what you mean by smart battery, if it's something like a power bank battery than it will already have a built in chip that regulates the charging when power charger is plugged in, overcharging etc.
If it's just a battery than best is to use a ready made module that has a charging chip like TP4056 and handles that job for you.

To build a system where the ESP32 knows what the level of battery charge is, there are few options.

1. You can use a simple "voltage divider" connected to one of the ESP32 ADC pins and measure the voltage and based on that figure out what the charge level is in the battery.

Done a quick google and here's an article that some nice guy has posted about it and included a little library that does the job.

[ESP32 – Getting Battery charging level](https://www.pangodream.es/esp32-getting-battery-charging-level)

2. Another option is to use an ESP32 board that already has the battery charging included and that you can simply get the values from.
   I have used one like this on one project and it worked well: [Heltec WiFi Kit32](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Diymore-Development-Wireless-Display-CP2102/dp/B0BGY69RCK/ref=sr_1_18_sspa?adgrpid=1175378828984755&hvadid=73461374984045&hvbmt=be&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=133603&hvnetw=s&hvqmt=e&hvtargid=kwd-73461311453935%3Aloc-188&hydadcr=19080_1836400&keywords=heltec%20esp32&qid=1701964002&sr=8-18-spons&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9tdGY&psc=1) or you have some like this [XIAO_ESP32C3](https://wiki.seeedstudio.com/XIAO_ESP32C3_Getting_Started/) it does have battery pins exposed on one side but can't remember if you need to add something extra to it.

Once you can monitor the battery than you can implement logic in your code that will handle low charge.

There is nothing special about PlatformIO regarding this, it's more deciding on the hardware and if you need any libraries or the ESP board handles it for you and you just keep checking a certain pin that will give you the charge values.

Comment: The hardware part is already decided. I will be using a wroom esp32 (Board in platformIO is nodemcu-32s, platform: espressif32, framework: Arduino but I did not decide yet whether to use .ino files or .cpp and .h files I am new to embedded programming so I am really not sure which option would be the best as a starting point for me to this field) . The battery is a smart battery (Lithium Ion battery from fey model number : PA-LEP1014 R001 and could handle SMBus protocol) and the charger also is a smart charger (from Fuyuan for 14.6V LiFePO4 Battery FY1501000.

Comment: If you are using platformIo then you have to use .cpp & .h files, which I definitely prefer than .ino and it gives you a much more flexibility with writing your code. If your battery supports SMBbus then you need to talk to it through that, I am pretty sure there is a library somewhere for the SMB bus. The rest as I said, use different sleep modes for the ESP to reduce consumption.

Comment: I have been struggling with finding a suitable library or project anywhere that could be the best reference for me to work on my project, any guidance in this regard would be much appreciated.